# Structure/Modify a particular row entry as a new column entry

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Below is how the data looks like-

```
Timestamp                  action_types       action_ID     name     x_ID
2019-02-17 07:11:19        action_1             12          ABC      444
2019-02-17 07:11:19        action_2             123         ABC      444
2019-02-17 07:11:19        action_3             1234        ABC      444
2019-02-17 07:11:19        action_4             12345       ABC      444
2019-02-18 07:12:19        action_1             56          DEF      555
2019-02-18 07:12:19        action_6             567         DEF      555
2019-02-19 07:10:19        action_4             1122        LMN      666
```

The action_types and action_ID are **different** in all records. 
Case 1: first 4 records the action_types and action_ID are different but all other columns are the same. In such a scenario, if we **do have** action_4 present then what I want to do is create another column **action_4** and insert the corresponding **action_ID** for all the similar records.

Case 2: Records 5 and 6 do not have **action_4** row so I want to insert **n/a** in **action_4 column.**

Case 3: has only action_4 so I remove the corresponding action_ID and insert that in action_4 column and insert n/a in action_types and action_ID column.

Expected result-

```
Timestamp                  action_types       action_ID     name     x_ID    action_4    
2019-02-17 07:11:19        action_1             12           ABC      444     12345
2019-02-17 07:11:19        action_2             123          ABC      444     12345
2019-02-17 07:11:19        action_3             1234         ABC      444     12345
2019-02-18 07:12:19        action_1             567          DEF      555      n/a
2019-02-18 07:12:19        action_6             567          DEF      555      n/a
2019-02-19 07:10:19        n/a                  n/a          LMN      666      1122
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(grp, remove)
FROM (
  SELECT * 
    REPLACE(
      IF(action_types = 'action_4', 'n/a', action_types) AS action_types, 
      IF(action_types = 'action_4', 'n/a', action_ID) AS action_ID
    ),
    IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN action_types = 'action_4' THEN action_id END) OVER(PARTITION BY grp), 'n/a') AS action_4,
    (action_types = 'action_4') AND (COUNTIF(action_types != 'action_4') OVER(PARTITION BY grp) != 0) remove
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      FORMAT('%t', (SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT(action_types, action_ID) FROM UNNEST([t]))) grp
    FROM `project.dataset.table` t
  ) 
)
WHERE NOT remove
```

If to apply to sample data in your question - result is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when action_type = 'action_4' then action_id end) over (partition by timestamp, name) as action_4
      from t
     ) t
where action_type <> 'action_4';
```

Comment: it gives me an error- Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): x_id

Comment: It is giving me an error associated with t.* as well

Comment: I have many columns that are same and not just timestamp, name in the real data. Should I include all of them in the partition by clause?

Comment: @user11035754 . . . (1) The duplicate column name was a typo.  (2) `t` is your table and alias.  (3) Whatever columns define a "group" is what you should use in the `partition by`.